# I have a mistake: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass and i dont know how delete notation in subscription table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know how update subject of teacher and delete notation (record) from subscription table

**teacher_controller**

```
 def update
        @subject = Subject.where("id=?", params[:subject_id]).first
        @teacher.subjects << @subject
        respond_to do |format|
          if @teacher.update(teacher_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @teacher, notice: 'Teacher was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @teacher.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

And what write in bellow code, that delete teacher and fields in subscription table - teacher_id and subject_id?

```
def destroy
    @teacher.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to teachers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**teachers/_form.html.erb (edit form)**

```
 <%= form_for(@teacher,:html => { class: 'login-form' })  do |f| %>

    <%= select_tag "subject_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@subjects, "id", "name") %>

    <% form %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :teachers do
        resources :subjects
    end
```

Comment: `options_from_collection_for_select(@subject, "id", "name")` it should be `@subject` not `@subjects`

Comment: In which view page, your teacher form resides? and what is the related action for that view?

Comment: You've defined `@subject` in your controller, but use `@subject` in your view!

Comment: Help me! I understand, but I update this teacher and save changes, subject of teacher don't change.

Comment: please share the code for the related action of your view page(the teacher edit form)?

Comment: I share code. Help me!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `@subject` in your controller and using `@subjects` in the `select_tag`

Change it to

```
<%= select_tag "subject_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@subject, "id", "name") %>
```

Comment: hehehehehehee my comment :)

Comment: I understand, but I update this teacher and save changes, subject of teacher don't change.

Comment: @RajarshiDas LOL :) It happens very often.But i really didn't see it coming.

Comment: @user3533435 What are you trying to do man! What are you up to?